# Porque desaparece mi ListView? Android Studio - Firebase

Tags: android-studio, firebase, listview

En mi app tengo un botón el cual hace una llamada a firebase para localizar ciertos keys con sus respectivos values, los cuales seran añadidos a un Array el cual sera mostrado en un Listview.

Al ingresar un valor en el `EditText`seguido de presionar el botón que hace la consulta con Firebase, me muestra los debidos registros correctamente, **el problema es que** si vuelvo a presionar el botón desaparece el `ListView`.

Estoy trabajando en un Fragment, **creo que el problema es que** al ultimo establezco que se limpie el Array para que cuando vuelva a presionar el botón pueda agregar otros registros dependiendo de lo que ingrese en el `EditText` pero lo que pasa es que desaparece.

Este es mi código:

```
private void fragment_rastreo(){
    mEstado = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.estado);
    mEstado2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.estado2);
    E_buscar = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.E_buscar);
    B_buscar = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.B_buscar);
    mProductosList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.productos_list);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContexto, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mProductos);
    mProductosList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    final String TAG = "RastreoFragment.java";

    B_buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String buscar = E_buscar.getText().toString().trim();

            mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        if (postSnapshot.getKey().equals(buscar)){
                            Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + postSnapshot.getKey());
                            Log.d(TAG, "Value: " + postSnapshot.getValue());
                            mEstado.setText("\nEl numero #" + buscar + " contiene: " + postSnapshot.getValue() + "\n");

                            mDatabase2 = mDatabase2.child(buscar);
                            mDatabase2.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                                    mEstado2.setText("\nLo que contiene este numero es:\n ");
                                    String value = dataSnapshot.getKey() + " " + dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                    mProductos.add(value);
                                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                           break;

                        }else{
                            if (buscar.equals("")){
                                mEstado.setText("\nIngrese un numero valido.\n");
                            }else {
                                mEstado.setText("\nEl numero #" + buscar + " no tiene registro.\n");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    mProductos.clear();
                    mEstado2.setText("");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Habia hecho esto en una app sin fragment y funcionaba correctamente pero al pasar el código a un Fragment se presento este error que desaparece el `ListView`.

Gracias.

Comment: Desaparece el listview? como sabes que desaparece y no carga datos a lo mejor ? por que añades el Logcat para ver hasta donde llega el proceso de manera correcta ..

Comment: Cierto tienes razón, no los está cargando/llamando. Tienes idea del porque?

Comment: Ahora por que limpias los datos cada vez que pides datos, si se supone que cada vez que presionas el botón llena de datos nuevos tu listview

Comment: Porque si no pongo eso la lista siempre se queda ahi y no cambia.

Comment: Después de realizar una consulta, cuando vuelves a hacer otra, ingresando nuevos datos en el `editText` a busca, te pasa lo mismo. O es solo cuando presionas el botón y dejas el `ediText` vacío.

Comment: Ya lo resolvi David, gracias. A continuación pondre la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

**Resuelto:**
En las siguientes lineas estaba declarando que "mDatabase2" obtuviera el child del texto ingresado entonces cuando volvia a hacer una consulta "mDatabase2" ya no tenia la referencia de la Firebase.

```
 mDatabase2 = mDatabase2.child(buscar);
                        mDatabase2.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
```

Decidi declarar otro `DatabaseReference` para que "mDatabase2" no borrara la referencia de Firebase:

```
mDatabase3 = mDatabase2.child(buscar);
                            mDatabase3.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
```